# audio streaming to the server

Tags: java, flash

i'm trying to create an application in flash that will record the sound from the user and will save the data on the server. can I do this saving the recorded audio to the server by using java script or java servlets and not by php?

Answer (score 0):

Question is too common, but definitely you can. As an concept you can try something like that. Override `doPost` method in your servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream in = (InputStream) request.getInputStream();

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        // save your data
    }
    in.close();
}
```

On the client side just post portions of data.

Comment: sir, I am new to flash technology. could you please tell me how to pass the stream to the servlet. I am working with https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder

Comment: I'm familiar with java and little bit with javascript, but not with Flash. I can't tell you exactly how it should be implemented in your case. Take a look at [ActionScript API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html). You have to perform HTTP POST on the client side and send your data as payload. On the server side servlet will process this request.